# How can i print out output based on user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

```
def take_order():
    list_of_drinks = ["coffee", "tea", "coca-cola"]

    user_required_items = []
    orders = int(input("how many types of drink will u be ordering? "))

    total_cost = 0

    for i in range(orders):
        drink = input("Please enter a drink:")
        drink = drink.capitalize()
        user_required_items.append(drink)
        qnt = int(input("Quantity:"))
        user_required_items.append(qnt)
        price1 = 0
        price2 = 0
        price3 = 0
        drink = drink.lower()
        if drink == "coffee":
            price1 = item["Coffee"]*qnt
        elif drink == "tea":
            price2 = item["Tea"]*qnt
        else:
            price3 = item["Coca-cola"]*qnt

        total_cost += price1+price2+price3
        print()
        print('Receipt')
        print('==============================')
        print(f'{"Drink":5s}:               {drink:>1s}')
        print(f'{"Quantity":8s}:{qnt:>13}')

    return total_cost
```

How can i print out the drinks and quantity based on what the user enter at orders?

This code is workable
full code link: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/ifokevahax.py

Comment: is there an error or issue with the code, if so, post the traceback.

Comment: <https://paste.pythondiscord.com/icehejuxiy.rb>  so even if i enter a drink not in the  menu the code will still use the price of the first item how can i prevent that.the proof is in the link

Comment: and also how can i make the loop go back to asking user the drinks they want after printing "Please enter a drink from the menu"

Comment: always put all information as text in question, not link to external page.

Comment: I don't uderstand why you use `'f'{"Quantity":8s}:{qnt:>13}'`  if you can put some text directly `f'Quantity:{qnt:>13}'` and it will be more readable.

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand what is the problem - it seems code works correctly. Loop works - it goes to beginning to ask for next drink. if you want to first ask for all drinks and later print all drinks then use two `for`-loops - first to ask for drinks, second to display drinks. And you will have to use some list to remeber all drinks between loops.

Comment: BTW: you could use `if drink.lower() in list_of_drinks:` to run code when drink is in menu. And later you can do `price = item[drink.capitalized()] * qnt`

Comment: BTW: it will be simpler to keep it as pairs `user_required_items.append( [drink, qnt] )`

Comment: @furas thanks for the comment i will go check it up!!

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I don't understand what is your problem. Loop works and ask for next drink and it displays drink.

But if you want to first get all drinks and later display all drinks then you should create separated loops for this - first only to get drinks, second only to display drinks.

Something like this.

BTW: I added few other changes.

```
menu = {
    'coffee':    {'name': 'Coffee',    'price': 4.00},
    'tea':       {'name': 'Tea',       'price': 3.00},
    'coca-cola': {'name': 'Coca-Cola', 'price': 2.00},
}

names = [item['name'] for item in menu.values()]

longest_name = max(names, key=len)
longest_name_len = len(longest_name)

for key, value in menu.items():
    name  = value['name']
    price = value['price'] 
    print(f"{name:{longest_name_len}} : ${price:.2f}")
    
    
def take_order():
    list_of_drinks = list(menu.keys())

    # --- get all drinks ---
    
    orders = int(input("How many types of drink will u be ordering? "))

    user_required_items = []
    total_cost = 0

    while orders:
        
        drink = input("Please enter a drink:")
        drink = drink.lower()
        
        if drink not in list_of_drinks:
            print('Wrong name.')
            print('Available:', ', '.join(names))
        else:
            orders -= 1
            
            qnt = int(input("Quantity:"))
        
            price = menu[drink]['price'] 
            cost = price * qnt

            user_required_items.append( [drink, qnt, price, cost] )

            total_cost += cost
        
    # --- display all drinks ---
    
    print('Receipt')
    print('==============================')

    for drink, qnt, price, cost in user_required_items:
        print(f'Drink:               {drink}')
        print(f'Quantity:            {qnt} * {price} = {cost}')

    print('==============================')
    print(f'Total:               {total_cost}')
        
    return total_cost #, user_required_items


take_order()
```

Comment: longest_name = max(names, key=len)
longest_name_len = len(longest_name) for this part is it refering to how long the name is then give the spacing?

Comment: yes, I use it to find  the longest name in menu - and then I can use this length to add spaces when I display menu.